# Show directly that $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-3}]$ is not a UFD, by finding an integer that factors into primes in more than one way.

Tags: number-theory

Show directly that $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-3}]$ is not a UFD, by finding an integer that factors into primes
in more than one way. Examine and explain how the two factorizations are related to the unique prime factorization in the quadratic integers in $ \mathbb Q[\sqrt{-3}] $

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I have no idea how to do this

Comment: Maybe you can start by writing out $(a + b\sqrt{-3})(c + d\sqrt{-3})$ and figure out how this can be an integer.

Comment: And you should probably know what $\mathcal O_{\mathbb Q[\sqrt{-3}]}$ is. And how $2$ factors there.

Comment: Whoever wrote your problem needs to fix it, too; you cannot factor a number into primes in two different ways; but you *can* factor it into **irreducibles** in two different ways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Render $4=2×2=(1+\sqrt{-3})(1-\sqrt{-3})$.  To reduce any of these factors you need a factor having the form $a+b\sqrt{-3}$ where $a^2+3b^2=2$, or unit other than the trivial units $\pm1$, but none exists.  So we are left with a non-unique factorization to irreducibles.

Answer (score 0):

*Hint:* Factor $4$ in two different ways.

Spoiler:

> $2 \cdot 2 = 4 = (1 + \sqrt{-3})(1 - \sqrt{-3})$. Prove that the factors are irreducible using the norm.

Comment: well, I’m still confused but thank you!